# issue with threading and facebook single sign on

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK to do the single sign on. Now when the app first launch I have a modal view controller showing the login page with 2 buttons, login with twitter and Facebook. When I press on login the Facebook dialog box shows up.. and it says that I have authenticated the app. So I click on OK. Then it goes back to the login view controller and when dismissing it, I got this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '<MKMapView: 0x2d1720; frame = (1.2941e-09 0; 4.70638e-36 1.66881e-07); transform = [1.6714e-07, 4.70638e-36, 1.67031e-07, 4.70647e-36, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)> initWithCoder:: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

This does not happen if I log out from facebook first, so then I have to enter my username and password and then login. How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe your code on how you do all you're telling would be helpful

Comment: I have a singleton object which is around 1000 line, should I post that here?

Comment: Nevermind, maybe your viewDidLoad: method of the MKMapView where you call the Facebook login, the delegate Login callbacks methods, or something useful

Comment: I uncomment everything in my viewDidLoad on MKMapView, so nothing is there again.. The MKMapView is initialized via IB and it is one of the view in a UITabBarController that I have

Answer (score 0):

U missing a line mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]init];

When it comes back to your view after facebook login put this where first your application function is called ie ViewDidLoad.

Comment: my mapView is initialized via IB

Comment: Try as i am saying as ur error says that only and.. on IB might be You have done it but when u call facebook new view is intialized budy. that way ur mapView is dereference as i guess . Atleast u can give a try if it isnt gose that way wil try something else.